# Bootstrap theming how to set colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-themes

I am attempting to build a theme in Bootstrap. Here is my custom .scss file. I want the color of the entry in a text box to change to the `$textColor`.

I was using this [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/#custom-color-modes) as an example. I have the data-bs-theme="corporate" in my html element.

I want to use a variable for my color vs hard-coding. Is that possible?

The reason is that I want to have shading based on that color and that color is not set by the marketing department yet.

```
$header-blue:  #1D46F3;
$textColor: #002579;

[data-bs-theme="corporate"] {
  --bs-body-color: #{to-rgb($textColor)};  /* This line does not work */
  --bs-body-color: $textColor;  /* This line does not work */
  --bs-body-color: #002579;  /* This line does work */

  --bs-body-color-rgb: #{to-rgb($white)};
  --bs-body-bg: var(--bs-white);
  --bs-body-bg-rgb: #{to-rgb($white)};
  --bs-emphasis-color:#{to-rgb($textColor)};
  --bs-table-color:#{to-rgb($textColor)};
  --bs-table-color-state:#{to-rgb($textColor)};
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you aren't using a full front end but rather just HTML?  How are you going to set dynamic values?

Comment: Why not follow the guide on customization at [the official website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/overview/)?

Comment: I am following the guide, I have included the link.  Unless I am doing something wrong.  Also, I am using a full front end this is just .scss file.  When compiled the 2 of the 3 lines do not work so, I am wondering what is the proper way to do this.

Comment: When you say "does not work", does that mean it isn't compiling into the CSS or the rule is being overridden in the browser? Can you see your attribute selector in the stylesheet?